# How do I use DataGrip to access a PostgreSQL instance behind a Docker virtual network?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have dockerized database microservices. I can run manual queries using the following:

```
$ ssh user@foo.domain.com
$ docker exec -it postgres bash
docker$ psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -d postgres
```

The web services all talk to one another using a Docker bridged virtual network `batman`.

```
networks:
  batman:
    driver: bridge
```

In alignment with PostgreSQL security best practices - I do *not* expose PostgreSQL port 5432 to the host machine at foo.domain.com. Only the sibling containers which are also in the 'batman' Docker network are allowed to connect to the database.

In a traditional DataGrip / PostgreSQL setup, I would ssh into the hosted box where PostgreSQL is served, and use a local PostgreSQL client (rules from: pg_hba.conf).

A Dockerized system requires one additional step (exec).

Seeing as DataGrip doesn't seem to allow prefixed connection commands, how do I use DataGrip to access a PostgreSQL instance behind a Docker virtual network?

Comment: certainly DataGrip doesn't allow prefixed connection commands, but does it at least let you specify the path to `psql`? if so, you could make a fake `psql` executable; a shell script containing `docker exec -it postgres psql $*` or similar.

Comment: Could you add that command to your login script for that user? That way the server automatically runs it instead of relying on DataGrip.

Comment: @Birchlabs - if its possible i cannot figure it out

Comment: @pucky124 - that would complicate company wide user management drastically

Comment: hm. you may have to write your own JDBC driver. as far as I can tell, the [official PostgreSQL JDBC driver](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc) does not invoke the psql binary anyway, so sadly it's probably not possible to make their driver point at a proxy binary.

Answer (score -3):

I think this should be possible:

- Add a simple container with an SSH server in the same (`batman`) network
- Set up your connection via SSH tunnel:
  [image: Screenshot of SSH/SSL tunnel option]
- Configure your connection as if you were on the network (so the host would be `postgres` AFAIR)